# How to relaunch an application as it is shut from within the app

Tags: c#, events, console-application

I realize that this question, or very similar ones, have been posted, but I'm having trouble with all other solutions. I'm new to programming, so any explanations would be greatly appreciated.

My goal is to make a simple joke application that relaunches itself whenever it is exited.
So far I have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit);
        Console.WriteLine("mytext");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myPath =Path.GetFullPath(@"MyApp.exe");
        Process.Start(myPath);
    }
```

However, I don't fully understand the appdomain line.(copied from another answer) It seems like it creates a new event that is triggered when the app is exited, which should be right. I get an error saying dotnet has stopped working when I run the application.

The application.exit method and the MSDN page on Application.ApplicationExit has no examples, leaving me a little confused.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It works for me, however are you sure the name of your app is `MyApp.exe`